# Received fatal alert, bad_certificate

Tags: java, ssl

I am trying to make an SSL conection to a server. I have created a Truststore and imported the server's certificate as well as mine as trusted entries into the Keystore. The server guys also have imported my certificate into their keystore. But when i try to connect, i get this error:

> Received fatal alert: bad_certificate

On the server, they are getting this error:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain

What could i be possibly be doing wrong?, How do i fix this error? I have been battling this issue for a very long time now.

My Client Code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.security.*;


import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.net.ssl.*;

public class SSLConnect {

public String MakeSSlCall(String meternum) {
    String message = "";
    FileWriter file = null;
    try {
        file = new FileWriter("C:\\SSLCERT\\ClientJavalog.txt");

    } catch (Exception ee) {
        message = ee.getMessage();

    }
    //writer = new BufferedWriter(file );
    try {
        file.write("KeyStore Generated\r\n");
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keystore.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\SSLCERT\\newclientkeystore"), "client".toCharArray());
        file.write("KeyStore Generated\r\n");
        Enumeration enumeration = keystore.aliases();
        while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            String alias = (String) enumeration.nextElement();
            file.write("alias name: " + alias + "\r\n");
            keystore.getCertificate(alias);
            file.write(keystore.getCertificate(alias).toString() + "\r\n");
        }
        TrustManagerFactory tmf =TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        tmf.init(keystore);
        file.write("KeyStore Stored\r\n");
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();
        context.init(null, trustManagers, null);

        SSLSocketFactory f = context.getSocketFactory();
        file.write("About to Connect to Ontech\r\n");
        SSLSocket c = (SSLSocket) f.createSocket("192.168.1.16", 4447);
        file.write("Connection Established to 196.14.30.33 Port: 8462\r\n");
        file.write("About to Start Handshake\r\n");
        c.startHandshake();

        file.write("Handshake Established\r\n");
        file.flush();
        file.close();
        return "Connection Established";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            file.write("An Error Occured\r\n");
            file.write(e.getMessage() + "\r\n");
            file.flush();
            file.close();
        } catch (Exception eee) {
            message = eee.getMessage();
        }
        return "Connection Failed";
    }
}
}
```

Keytool commands for creating my truststore

keytool -import -alias client -file client.cer -keystore MyKeystore -storepass mystore

keytool -import -alias server -file server.cer -keystore MyKeystore -storepass mystore

And i have also added the two certificates to my cacerts keystore

Comment: You should write here the code you use for the connection, for the creation of truststore and for import of certificates. BTW, are you sure you have imported the certificate of the server you need?

Comment: @Gangnus I have added my code and my keytool commands for storing my certificate. is there anything i am doing wrong here?

Comment: I was invited to judge the possible closing of your question. Be careful, mostly questions without code are considered as useless. And in your case it really WAS so. I am glad that my voting against closing was supported by your fast edition. I would also advise marking the place where the code fails. Socket creation or handshaking? Also, you should put here the stacktrace you got from the exception. And maybe, the content of socket 'c', before and after the fail. As for your style, I would advise using logger instead of that 'file', just for future. And the name 'c' does not tell much, too.

Comment: You create socket to "192.168.1.16", 4447, but report connection to 196.14.30.33 Port: 8462. Something must be false.

Comment: @Gangnus  am not trying to connect to 196.14.30.33 : 8462, from my code am just writing that port to a file, i should actually have commented it out tho. My code breaks at  c.startHandshake();

Comment: `bad_certificate` means "A certificate was corrupt, contained signatures that did not
       verify correctly, etc."

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but I had to face similar issue. Here is my working code:

```
    Properties systemProps = System.getProperties();
    systemProps.put("javax.net.debug","ssl");
    systemProps.put("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","<path to trustore>");
    systemProps.put("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","password");
    System.setProperties(systemProps);

    SSLContext sslcontext;
    KeyStore keyStore;
    final char[] JKS_PASSWORD = "password".toCharArray();
    final char[] KEY_PASSWORD = "password".toCharArray();

    try {
        final InputStream is = new FileInputStream("<path_to_keystore.pkcs12>");
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
        keyStore.load(is, JKS_PASSWORD);
        final KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init(keyStore, KEY_PASSWORD);

        sslcontext=SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslcontext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failure initializing default SSL context", ex);
    }

    SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = sslcontext.getSocketFactory();  
    DataOutputStream os = null;

    try {
        SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket();
        sslsocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), connectTimeout);
        sslsocket.startHandshake();

        os = new DataOutputStream(sslsocket.getOutputStream());
        // log.info("Sending echo packet");
        String toSend = "{\"echo\":\"echo\"}";
        os.writeBytes(toSend);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```